# How can I pack procedural textures into a .gltf file?

Tags: export, procedural, gltf

I have a noise texture like this:

[image]

And I want it to be exported into a .gltf file.  However, when I exported this as a .glb, the texture was gone and the cube was just white.  I'd like for this to work, as I'm going to make a few procedural textures with the noise texturing modifier.

If I can't export procedural textures into GLTF formats, what format should I use that will support noise texturing/node map exporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should "bake" procedural textures into image textures, prior to exporting to any format.  The "Bake" panel is powered by the Cycles engine, so is not available if your engine is set to Eevee or Workbench.  It's in the "Render Properties" panel after switching to Cycles.

Doing this gets the work done "in advance."  The software loading the glTF file won't have to work through your set of material nodes for every pixel in every animation frame, instead it will look up the answer from the baked image map, which depending on the node tree can be substantially faster.  It does limit the available resolution, to the size of the texture you baked.

You'll need a UV atlas on the object, to act as texture coordinates for the image being baked.

Also, you need an Image Texture node to act as the bake target, inside the material(s) being baked.  This node needs to be "Active" (Selected with the white outline around it) at the time the "Bake" button is pressed.

[image: screenshot of node tree with white outline]

Various YouTube tutorials are also available, one in the comments below, and [another one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNE3z424YpM&list=PLvdhJ__UbhZ6mst0xgd_S3oSmdRcEiKCp&index=6) that I might have had something to do with.

Comment: I am baking the procedural texture right now.  For anyone reading this in the future - the only way to get a noise/procedural texture into a glb is to bake it.  which takes FOREVER! But here's a good guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYvgFWEiNp8

Comment: Remember, "Bake" is a special type of render powered by Cycles.  The "Render Properties -> Sampling" panel is in effect here, and by default "Render" is set to 128 samples per pixel.  For a bake texture like this, you might be able to drop down to just 1 sample, and get a big speedup.  For baked AO, you can get better quality by upping the samples, along with a slowdown.

Comment: Imagine you start hearing baking when you got into coding. Na bro I aint baking